# Ошибка в тексте на странице справки

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

На странице https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user написано:

> Как другие могут увидеть вашу развернутую карточку пользователя?
> Если кто-либо из участников сообщества желает просмотреть вашу карточку, он может в вопросе, ответе или списке пользователей навести курсор на **вашу** аватар, и поверх нее появится развернутая карточка с дополнительной информацией. Она также называется развернутой карточкой.

Вместо слова "вашу" должно быть "ваш".

Comment: Ещё "нее" -> "неё".

Comment: Или можно заменить следующее слово на "аватарку"