# Почему не обновляют справку?

Tags: поддержка, справка

Я задал два вопроса о небольших дефектах в справке:

| вопрос | задан | изменения |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Ошибка в тексте на странице справки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12053) | 8 месяцев назад | убрать одну букву |
| [Неправильный MarkDown в справке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12358) | 1 месяц назад | добавить два пробела |

Разве изменить справку так сложно?

Comment: Я так понимаю модераторы не имеют такой возможности, а сотрудникам не до этого  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А вообще мелкие дефекты - не так уж серьёзно. Потому что на некоторых страницах справки я вообще устаревшую информацию находил. Например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions): статуса [требует-правки] давно не существует.

Comment: @Зонтик в текущих условиях проще считать, что не можем.

Answer (score 2):

Информация не точная, но вроде как всё именно так.

Обновлять справку без каких-либо известных ограничений могут только сотрудники Stack Overflow. Модераторы могут править одновременно несколько (максимум 3?) страниц справки, но для этого КМ (или другой сотрудник тоже?) должен выставить признак для конкретной страницы, которую предполагается править.

Поэтому всё так тяготно. Ибо КМ толком нет у нас.

Comment: То есть все эти новости "у нас новый КМ" - это слухи?

Comment: Nicolas  нас покинул?

Comment: @avp [уж как 5 лет скоро](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217)

Comment: @avp https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217

Comment: @Зонтик анонса ещё не было официального