# КМ придёт.... А кто он? И как это на нас повлияет?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, stackexchange, менеджер-сообщества

Есть [ответ @Nofate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12267/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%87%d1%83%d1%80-%d1%80%d1%8c%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c/12417#12417), в котором говорится, что у нас новый КМ.

Есть пост [А не устроить ли нам выборы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12418/%d0%90-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b?cb=1). В нём тоже говорится о КМ'е. И есть старая публикация (5-летней давности) о том, что [у сообщества не будет КМ'а](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7545/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bf-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bf).

КМ, как я понял - это `Community Manager`.

Вопросы:

1. Это управляющий конкретно нашего сообщества, или это какой-то общий управляющий сети `StackExchange`?
2. Если это только наш КМ, то неужели настали времена, когда станет легче решать [конфликты сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12267/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%87%d1%83%d1%80-%d1%80%d1%8c%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c), и наконец-то в справке будет актуальная информация (а не как на [этой странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)), да ещё и [без дефектов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12503/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83)?
3. Если КМ - КМ всей сети, то как он на нас повлияет?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Исходя из моего опыта модерирования другого сайта сети [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/):

- КМ — community manager — не закрепляется за конкретным сообществом. Таким образом, на ваш вопрос 2 ответ отрицательный. Однако это на значит, что не стоит направлять усилия на актуализацию справки и разрешения конфликтов, просто ожидать улучшения именно сейчас — причин нет.
- Исторически, много вещей в режиме ручного управления решал для Stack Overflow на русском Николас. С течением времени, его "должностные инструкции" менялись и меняются, поэтому, вероятно, и возник [этот пост](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/337980).
- Stack Exchange предоставляет модераторам разные возможности эскалации и контакта с КМ-ами. Включая формальные и неформальные методы. Разумеется, при наличии выделенного КМ — многое можно решить быстрее через чат и т.д. Однако, это не способствует образованию устойчивых процессов и зависит от наличия времени у КМ-а.

По Stack Overflow на русском:

- Я не вижу причин, по которым ситуация с КМ-ом для Stack Overflow на русском является критической (модераторы могут меня подправить).
- Разумеется, это сообщество отличается от большинства других тем, что в нем используется русский язык, что потенциально осложняет работу КМ и взаимодействие с модераторами. Это все равно мне не кажется достаточно веской причиной.
- Часто, для локализованных сайтов на неанглийском языках, взаимодействие ведет КМ, обладающий некоторыми навыками в этом языке. Но необязательно. Всегда можно попросить модератора ввести неговорящего на (условно) русском языке КМа в курс дела для принятия решения. Было бы желание.
- Наличие выделенного КМ также потенциально негативно влияет на "демократию". Работа сообщества с сообществом, модераторов с сообществом и сообщества с модераторами должна составлять 99% усилий, и эскалация на КМ — редка.
- По поводу "редкости" необходимости эскалации со мной можно поспорить, однако большая часть таких запросов - это о коррекции голосов (targeted voting, voting fraud) и слития учетных записей дубликатов. Эти вопросы решаются только на уровне КМ, однако вряд ли имеют аспект срочности к ним.

[Более детально о роли Community Manager и тем людям, кто составляют данную команду.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/383809)

Comment: community manager вроде как закреплялись за локализованными сайтами

Comment: _слития учетных записей дубликатов_ - очень частый запрос на самом деле

Comment: @Grundy частый, но я бы не сказал, что срочный.

Comment: Ну это как считать

Comment: К нам едет ревизор?))